Eszett in all capital letter words
When we (for titles) change the capitalization of a word, to all caps I have been told to change eszett to double ss.
However I never heard this during my studies, is this actually a guideline that is generic? Or just local guide? I see it being repeated here: https://germantakeaways.com/german-s-eszett/

That is the general rule used to be that an ß has to be replaced by SS when the word is captialized - on grounds that there is (or rather was) no captial letter ß as it is never present at the beginning of a word.
This somewhat changed in 1996 when such letter was devised (which incidentially looks quite similar to the not-capitalized version; and the captialized version is not on keyboards), so that now both are possible, using a captial-letter ß, or replacing it with a SS. You will still find it mostly being replaced by SS when using all captials for words.

You can produce capital ẞ by pressing Shift+AltGr+ß on a German keyboard in Windows.

Here is the guidance from Duden https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppel-s-und-scharfes-s
Bei Verwendung von Großbuchstaben steht traditionellerweise SS für ß. In manchen Schriften gibt es aber auch einen entsprechenden Großbuchstaben; seine Verwendung ist fakultativ ‹§ 25 E3›.
Zum Beispiel
STRASSE, AUSSEN, FUSSBALL
Auch: STRAẞE, AUẞEN, FUẞBALL


The following applies only to German Standard German and Austrian Standard German, but not to Swiss Standard German. German Standard German is an official language in Germany, Belgium, Luxembourg, Denmark (North Silesia) and Namibia. It is also one of the 24 official languages of the European Union, although the EU-Version contains 23 additional words from Austrian German. Austrian Standard German is an official language in Austria and Italy (South Tyrol). Swiss Standard German is an official language in Switzerland and Liechtenstein. (All named countries also have other official languages, some of them only in smaller regions, except Liechtenstein.)
The rule that the letter "ß" must be converted to "SS" when a word is written in uppercase was a hard rule before 29 June 2017. But on 29 June 2017, the German Spelling Council updated the German spelling rules in a press release. Since then, the capital letter "ẞ" can also be used for this purpose.
Therefore, these two spellings are now equally correct:

HAUPTSTRASSE
HAUPTSTRAẞE

In the usual lower case, only this version is still correct:

Hauptstraße

The version "Hauptstrasse" is only a tolerated variant, which is generally considered incorrect. It is tolerated if the author is unable to write the letter "ß" for technical reasons. Not knowing how to write the letter is not such a technical reason. However, an IT system that cannot display the letter "ß" is such a reason, as well as a typewriter on which this letter does not exist.
The spelling reform of 29 June 2017 was only made possible because the Unicode Consortium added the uppercase character "ẞ" to the character set of Unicode version 5.1.0 nine years earlier, on 4 April 2008, under code point U+1E9E and the name "Latin Capital Letter Sharp S". ("Sharp S" is "scharfes S" in German, which the name of this letter in Austrian German. German German uses another name: "Eszett".) This was the first step in creating the technical conditions for the use of this character.
There have been repeated attempts to establish the capital letter "ẞ" in German orthography since the 19th century, but these attempts were unsuccessful until 2017.

A final word on the Swiss variety of German, which is the official language of Switzerland and Liechtenstein:
There is no "ß" (and therefore also no "ẞ") in Swiss German. This letter is always replaced by "ss" or "SS" in Swiss German.
The 1876 Orthographic Conference was the first to define a unified orthography for the German language. This conference recommended that the character sequence "ſs" (long S, round S) shall be replaced by the ligature "ß" in book printing. It was not until the spelling reform of 1901 that this recommendation, which had previously applied only to book printing, became a universal standard. Switzerland (and with it Liechtenstein) initially adhered to this standard, but deviated from it more and more over time. The reason for this is probably Switzerland's multilingualism. The letter "ß" is only used in German, but not in the other three official languages of Switzerland (French, Italian and Romansch). Since 1938, this letter has not been taught in Swiss schools, and typewriters made for the Swiss market have had a German keyboard, but without the "ß" character. Instead, the French accents are easier to type on. However, the "ß" character was not officially removed from Swiss correspondence until 2006.
